# Why I am able to use Arrays.asList method with an object declared for interface, List, but not when it is declared as an instance of class ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, collections

```
//Splitting a string and passing it to a String Array
String[] b1 = a1.split("");

//The Following throws a compile-time error
ArrayList<String> arrayList1 =  new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList1 = Arrays.asList(b1);

//The following works
List<String> arrayList1 =  new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList1 = Arrays.asList(b1);
```

I want to know why the first approach throws error whereas the second one works well? `ArrayList` implements `List` interface, so it should work well.

Comment: All German Sheppards are dogs, but not every dog is a German Sheppard. Here: an `ArrayList` "is-a" `List`. So you can assign an `ArrayList` to `List`. But a `List` could also be of another (runtime) type, so you cannot assign `List` to the more specific `ArrayList`.

Comment: Note that the list returned by `Arrays.asList` is not `java.util.ArrayList`. It is a completely different class which is also named `ArrayList`, placed inside `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`

Comment: You have to understand *references*. Your variables have a *reference* type and assigning a new reference overwrites the old. Overwriting the reference has nothing to do with the object. In other words, the initialization `arrayList1 =  new ArrayList<String>()` is entirely pointless when you overwrite the reference right in the next statement with a different reference. The assignment is valid when the variable’s type is compatible with the reference. The old reference and the object it pointed to, are entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

> `ArrayList` implements `List` interface, so it should work well.

Nope, that's not how that works. If something returns an implementation of an interface you can assign it to an object declared as that interface, not the other way around.

That's what you're doing when you're doing

```
List<String> arrayList1 =  new ArrayList<String>();
```

Which is totally legal.

But what if `asList` returns something that is a List but not an ArrayList (which is what's happening here)? You get an error, because you're assigning something that is not an `ArrayList` (and does not descend from it) to an `ArrayList`.

Also notice that as soon as you do `arrayList1 = Arrays.asList(b1);` in the second test, the fact that you assigned a new `ArrayList` to `arrayList1` is totally irrelevant, as you're overwriting it next line, so `arrayList1` is just a `List`, as declared.

Answer (score 2):

Java is *statically* typed, when you say a variable is a `String` then you can't assign an `int` to it. The same goes for your example. When you declare `arrayList1` as a an `ArrayList<String>` then you can't assign a `List<String>` to it. Because you can't be sure that the value returned from `Arrays.asList()` is really an instance of `java.util.ArrayList`.

Also be careful there exists two java classes with the name `ArrayList`. The one from `java.util` and the one from `java.util.Arrays`. The former is `public` and the latter is `private` inside the `Arrays` class

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.asList(b1) returns an object of type java.util.Arrays.ArrayList which is a nested class within Arrays.

In other words, your question is why b1 of type java.util.Arrays.ArrayList cannot be casted into arrayList1 which is of type java.util.ArrayList : these are two completely different types not related at all.

If you need a java.util.ArrayList, you can just create a copy:

ArrayList arrayList1 =  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(b1));

Regards